# Filter a view by the current year

Tags: list-view

A view I created is supposed to filter by the current year. The formula should compare the current year with a column which only has the year.

I don't know how to always get the current year.

I tried creating a calculated column with this formula "Year([Today])" but sharepoint does not like it.

I tried using this formula "Year(Today)" and the view does not return any items.

How do I compare a column with the current year? I am unable to get the current year.

Answer (score 2):

Check this workaround and see if it helps:

[SharePoint TODAY field and calculated fields...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2006/03/16/552314.aspx)

I used it once before and it works.

I hope you are aware that calculated columns are calculated when item is updated. So after 31.12. 00:00 your calculated columns will no longer be valid (if items are not updated).

Comment: Ah yes, I nicknamed this the 'Overworked Secretary' problem (on my company's blog, that mentions our product): http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-use-today-in-a-sharepoint-list/ This is purely informational on the subject, and won't help answer the question, unfortunately.

Comment: @StuartPegg Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You might need two calculated columns.  One which is the jan/1/year and the other which is dec/31/year.

```
=TEXT(Date,"01/01/yyyy")

=TEXT(Date,"12/31/yyyy")
```

Then in your filter you can have it setup so that the first column is less than today and the second column is greater than today.

There might be a better way but this was my first thought.

Comment: Well, how exactly do you filter them? In your solution there is still the need of the current year...

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved it using something like this 
http://sivanesanb.blogspot.ch/2011/11/how-to-use-filters-in-sharepoint-to.html#!/2011/11/how-to-use-filters-in-sharepoint-to.html

Also did another one for the Quarter using the formula 
=ROUNDDOWN(((INT(MONTH([Created]))-1)/3),0)+1