# Showing the latest content added to a site

Tags: 2007

Is it possible to list all the content that was added to a site in a date range? E.g. show me all content added yesterday.

This is for MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Content Query Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx) to display eg. all documents in entire site collection based on custom filter/query.

To use time span as filter take a look at this links (both links for 2010 but it's same as in 2007):

- Simple date filter: [Date Range in a Content Query Web Part](http://arabic2000.com/blog/index.php/archives/44)
- Advanced formating: [Sharepoint 2010 xslt date formatting](http://labs.steveottenad.com/sharepoint-2010-xslt-date-formatting/)

You will encounter some issues if your goal is to combine different content types (eg. mix list items with documents). Also customization is sometimes tricky but there are tons of examples out there eg.  [Customizing the Content Query Web Part and Custom Item Styles](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx)

**Addition**

Some extra links regarding Today issue in 2007:

- [How to: Customize the Content Query Web Part by using Custom
  Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Filter a view by the current year](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20405/filter-a-view-by-the-current-year/20407#20407)

Comment: Im happy customising CQWP and DVWP, and had considered this. I Wasnt sure how much of a negative impact it would have if it was looking at every single item that exists on the site.

Comment: You need to be careful when running queries against whole site collection (performance issue). IMO using it for aggregation of just one content type and with time span filter should be ok. However it really depends on your specific requirements and amount of data you are querying. There is no other or better solution - even if you develop custom web part you will again face same problems with speed, performance... If you have 'tons of items' you can use one CQWP per site (or some other kind of grouping like for several sub sites) and not just one CQWP for entire site collection.

Comment: Your links are specific to 2010 Verdan. The problem with the CQWP in 2007 is that (as far as im aware) you cannot filter by [Today]-1 for example. I cannot create calculated columns on every list/library.

Comment: Sorry, since I didn't do any serious work on 2007 for year or even more and I forgot most of it :) I have included some more info in  my answer - hope it helps. Btw if someone presented me this request I would instantly start developing custom web part with [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I create web part page, and make a dashboard out of it. I set each list to display with anything that's been modified in the last 7 days.

Comment: This sounds like you are using dashboard webparts to query specific lists. This wont work for me as the business are unable to specify which lists they want to look at, so it need to be everything.

Comment: There is also a "What's New" web part that does something similar. that should be "out of the box", but once again you need to know the lists.